# c++ lambda: Currying sum function: returns different results using capture by value vs by reference

Tags: c++, lambda, functional-programming, currying, generic-lambda

I have a very simple recursive lambda which calculates sum of given 2 numbers:

```
auto sum_v1 = [](auto first){
  return [first](auto second){
    return first + second;
  };
};

sum_v1 (1)(2); // returns 3, OK
```

Now the same function, using capture by reference for arg first.

```
auto sum_v2 = [](auto first){
  return [&first](auto second){
    return first + second;
  };
};

sum_v2 (1)(2); // returns 4, NOT OK
```

`sum_v2` gets the argument `first` as `2` and arg `second` is also `2`.

I know how to get the right result. I could use either the sum_v1 OR sum_v3 (shown below).

```
// accept arg first using r-value reference
auto sum_v3 = [](auto&& first){
  return [first](auto second){
    return first + second;
  };
};

sum_v3 (1)(2); // returns 3, OK
```

How is `sum_v2`, while creating the lambda, is seeing the arg `first` as 2. I am struggling to understand that.

Could you please give me some hint(s) to understand this better? I am using gcc.9.2.0 with -std=c++17 on rhel 7.

Thanks,
Gaurav

Comment: What makes you think "`sum_v2` gets the argument `first` as `2` and arg `second` is also `2`?" Testing I get a return of `3`?

Comment: @David: which compiler are you using? I have updated my details in my post.

Comment: @David: Okay, I understand what you have said sir. You are right. sum_v2 is not getting the first argument as '2'. It does get it as '1'. My sentence is wrong. I will correct it now. Thank you for bringing it to my attention. Much appreciated.

Comment: You have a point. On gcc 9.2 with `-std=c++17` I get `"warning: ‘first’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]"` -- so there is a problem (either with the compile or with v2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
auto sum_v2 = [](auto first){
  return [&first](auto second){
    return first + second;
  };
};
```

Is undefined behavior, as you are taking a reference to a local variable `first` whose lifetime ends before it is used.  As with all UB, anything could happen.  On your machine it seems that `first` ends up referencing `second` instead, but that's not guaranteed.  The code could crash on other systems, or produce the expected result, but you can't rely on it.

With `-Wall -Werror` you wouldn't even be able to compile this bad code.  Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/3gYx7q

Comment: I am checking this but kindly note that the said flags don't make any difference and it still does compile. Here is output from my system:
`
20200126 18:23 [compuser@lenovoe470:singles]$  cat abc.cpp ; g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Werror abc.cpp && echo [$(./a.out)]
#include <iostream>

int main() {
auto sum_v2 = [](auto first){
  return [&first](auto second){
    return first + second;
  };
};

std::cout << sum_v2 (1)(2) << std::endl; // returns 4, NOT OK
};
[4]
20200126 18:23 [compuser@lenovoe470:singles]$  
`

Comment: GCC will only flag this code if compiling with optimization enabled.  See the demo link in my answer.

Comment: Answer accepted. Now I understand the behavior. It was not evident to me before. Thank you also for showing me difference between no optimization & optimization turned on. I should now opt for -O3 -Werror -Wall flags when I am studying and testing. Cheers!